# C# new web browser library

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have to perform a task of navigation to certain url and click few buttons on that page. But  i want to do using proxy and in multiple instance of web browser. I want to use multiple thread create a web browser instance, put a new proxy in that browser and navigate to url. Each thread will create a new broswer instance. Native [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

does not allow to put multiple proxy as it uses IE. So my ques is, is there some other webbrowser library out there that i can use to do stuff like DevXpress and other library. I dont want to use HttpClient

Comment: You should use `HttpClient` or Selenium, depending on whether you need to execute JS code.

Comment: i am not too good with HTTPCLIENT, i have to stream video from server. its like youtube version but at smaller scale. How can i do it. can you point me to a good tut